# How to use order by to sort according to current date?

Tags: mysql

here is my code in which i tried to sort my result to get data according to current date..

> What i need is to get that date on top whose jb_expiry_date is closer to current date

```
    SELECT vm_jobs_category.*
           , vm_jobs.* 
           , DATE_FORMAT(vm_jobs.jb_expiry_date,'%Y%m%d') AS pub
           , vm_seo_detail.* 
           , vm_publications.* 
      FROM vm_jobs 
INNER JOIN vm_jobs_category 
        ON (vm_jobs.jb_jc_id = vm_jobs_category.jc_id ) 
INNER JOIN vm_seo_detail 
        ON (vm_jobs.jb_id = vm_seo_detail.sd_ty_id AND vm_seo_detail.sd_ty = 'vm_jobs' ) 
INNER JOIN vm_publications 
        ON (vm_jobs.jb_id = vm_publications.ty_id AND vm_publications.ty_name = 'vm_jobs' AND vm_publications.status = '1')
     WHERE (vm_jobs.jb_expiry_date != '' AND vm_jobs.jb_expiry_date != '1970-01-01' AND vm_jobs.jb_expiry_date != '0000-00-00') 
     ORDER BY pub DESC
```

Comment: Why do you have dates like `1970-01-01` and `0000-00-00` in your database? This looks like super dirty data in need of some very aggressive cleaning.

Comment: `ORDER BY jb_expiry_date desc` try this

Comment: @Bhargav.. it shows only in desc form but here i want it as per today date on top and rest other in asc order

Comment: Use `ORDER BY (case when jb_expiry_date = current_date then 0 else 1 end) ASC, jb_expiry_date ASC`

Comment: @joanolo.. it sort the data but still it shows result according to asc order..not  current date on top..

Comment: Do you have any `jb_expiry_date` which is the `current_date`? Or do you want to *add an extra row that doesn't exist with the `current_date`*?

Comment: @joanolo..yes ..can we do that..i have tried to sort it with comparing to $current_date(variable)..but still it not work may b i am doing it wrong..

Answer (score 0):

Simply calculate the difference to the current date (in whatever unit suits you) and order by this.

```
...
ORDER BY TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, vm_jobs.jb_expiry_date, NOW())
```

- [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)'s the docu about this function